# Do I have a way to avoid re-creating lots of String objects?

Tags: java, string, object, memory

My project uses Javascript and Java (Android) for the client and Java for the backend.

When I started working on my project, I stored dates as days from epoch (long) and all was good. I then found out that my project doesn't work well with timezones. Suddenly dates were +1 -1 days off. Depending on the client's location in the world.

After a short investigation, I saw that the foolproof way to avoid it was to store the dates as String yyyy-MM-ddT00:00 so when using the Javascript's new Date(dateStr), it creates it correctly and all was good. Ofcourse I could store the dates as yyyy-MM-dd and just send it to the client as yyyy-MM-ddT00:00 but that won't solve the question I have.

After that, I was wondering whether Java (backend) is handled correctly. I use LocalDate when I want to "play" with dates and `LocalDate.parse` doesn't like yyyy-MM-ddT00:00 format, instead it works with yyyy-MM-dd so whenever I needed dates, I did `LocalDate.parse(dateStr.substring(0,10))`. LocalDateTime does work with yyyy-MM-ddT00:00 but I don't need the time part and it had its own issues, which I don't remember what they were at the moment.

So now I have a lot of String manipulation (inside loops) that actually creates more String objects. One can say it's not that much of a stress and I shouldn't pay attention to that but I want to make sure I'm not missing something and maybe there's another way (maybe silly enough that I've missed) to overcome this.

Thanks

**Update:** The events are stored from a different source and only the date itself is important so if an event happened on 2020-06-17, this is the date all users should see, no matter where they are.

I'm using `new Date(dateStr)` in Javascript. If dateStr is 2020-06-17, the date object uses the client's timezone and the date might be +-1 depending on the client's timezone. If dateStr is 2020-06-17T00:00 then the date object is created as expected no matter where the client is located.

Assuming the above, which I hope is clearer now, creating String objects over and over again is a memory stress that I should consider or is it something Java handles with no problem and I shouldn't worry about this?

My question was closed and I was told to edit it to be more focused. After editing my question, how can I re-open my question to answers?

Comment: Before you go any further, you need to decide on the following: If an Android device in e.g. New York saves a date/time of 2020-06-16T21:04, how should another Android device in e.g. Paris display that date/time value? Unchanged as 2020-06-**16**T**21**:04, or adjusted for time zone as 2020-06-**17**T**03**:04?

Comment: Typically your backend should be saving in GMT, which is exactly what epoch time is based on. Your UI should be translating from GMT to the local time zone. That said, it's unhelpful to describe your code. What you should be doing instead is posting the code in question and indicating specifically what kind of technical issue you're having. For all anyone knows, the code is perfect, but there's no way to tell because you don't bother to show it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. There is no need to translate dates and times, everybody should see the same date. I hope my additional info answered your comment as well.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to be about the issue you had with date being displayed differently for different clients throughout the world, then we can vote to reopen. Right now it's not clear if you're asking about dates and time zones or about the performance of strings, and the first question is more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, storing dates in terms of days since some epoch only works if everyone who uses your system is using the same time zone. If two different users in different time zones have a different idea about the date on which some event occurred (e.g., the person in New York says that the system crashed on Sunday night, but the the person in Hong Kong says it crashed on Monday morning), then you have to store the time zone in which the event occurred in order to show the date of that event accurately.

But if that's the situation you're in, why not just store the time zone along with the date? There's no compelling reason to combine the date and timezone into a string.

When you parse a ISO-formatted timestamp into a `LocalDate` using only the first 10 characters, be aware that you're losing the time zone information. Implicitly the `LocalDate` that you get is in the time zone of the original timestamp. So if the original timestamp is New York time, and you take the date part and add 1 day, then you'll get the next day in the New York time zone. But if you then take the date from a second timestamp, you can't compare it to the date you got from the first timestamp, in terms of determining if it represents the "same day." You can only test for "same day" if both dates are implicitly in the same time zone.

UPDATE

After reading your additional comments, I realize that what's happening is this. You have a date stored in your database, like 2020-06-15. You send that to the UI as the string `'2020-06-15'` and then do `new Date('2020-06-15')` and then you're surprised when you render the date in the UI and get June 14!

This is the transformation that happens:

- The string `'2016-06-15'` gets parsed into a JavaScript `Date` representing midnight *UTC* on the June 15.
- When you render the date, it gets converted into a string using the browser's local time zone, which (if you're in the United States) will give you June 14, because at midnight UTC on June 15 it's still June 14 in all time zones west of Greenwich.

You discovered that if you make the string "2020-06-15T00:00" that it works, because now JavaScript uses the browser's local time zone to parse the string. In other words, this string means midnight local time, not UTC, on June 15. So now the sequence is:

- `'2020-06-15T00:00'` gets parsed using the local time zone and becomes June 15 4:00AM UTC.
- When you render the date, it gets converted back to local time and is rendered as June 15.

The easiest way to avoid all this messiness is just to send the regular date string `'2020-06-15'` to the UI and render it using `DateTimeFormat`, specifying the time zone as UTC:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {timeZone: 'UTC'}).format(d)
```

Since dates in JavaScript are always UTC, and you're asking `DateTimeFormat` to output the date in UTC, no date shift occurs.

You could also use the `Date` methods `getUTCFullYear`, `getUTCMonth`, etc. to get the date components and format them however you like.

Once you're no longer sending dates back and forth with "T00:00" appended, you can just use `LocalDate` on the Java side.

Don't spend even a second worrying about the time required to manipulate strings. Think about the incredible amount of string manipulation that is necessary to build even a simple web page. A few more strings here and there isn't going to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for answering, please read my additional info, I hope it explains the issue a bit more.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I discovered Intl Object not long time ago and didn't think of trying it for this issue as well. Good catch. I will try it soon and mark as answered if applicable. Again, thanks.